# Configurar Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando configurar phpmyadmin pero cuando voy a ingresar me pide clave y no le he puesto ninguna recién instalo solo el phpmyadmin sin el xampp ¿Cual es la configuración adecuada?. esto se encuentra dentro del config.inic.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';


/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] =false;
```

Comment: Si la clave es `''` (vacio) puedes ingresar lo mismo (vacio) y deberías ingresar...  o cambias el AllowNoPassword a true... aunque, DEBERIAS tener clave... por más simple que sea... ejemplo `usuario: root, clave: root`

Comment: @Excorpion me salio este mensaje : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: ¿Instalaste el motor de base de datos e iniciaste el servicio?

Comment: Si claro @Triby pero me dice igual: El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso

Comment: Estás seguro que no tienes clave ? XD

Comment: Ya logre configurarlo muchas gracias